# My c# ComboBox does not call the getter after selecting an item. Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I have an Combobox with SelectedItem. If I select an item my setter does some calculation and perhaps I want to reset the value to the old one. Unfortunatly my view does no refresh.

I have the following ComboBox :

```
<ComboBox BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0"
  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsVS.View}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >

</ComboBox>
```

Here are the properties of my ViewModel:

```
private CollectionViewSource _itemsVS;
public CollectionViewSource ItemsVS
{
    get { return _itemsVS; }
    set
    {
        _itemsVS = value;
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemsVS"));
    }
}


private ItemViewModel _selectedItem;
public ItemViewModel SelectedItem
{
    get
    { 
        // after setting the old value in the setter the getter is not called
        // and the view is not refreshed
        return _selectedItem; 
    }
    set
    {
        var old = _selectedItem;
        _selectedItem = value;
        // After some logic I want to have the old value!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        _selectedItem = old;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));


    }
}
```

Comment: If you set the property back to it's original value before you have called `PropertyChanged`, what's to refresh? Nothing has changed.

Comment: please tag your question with WPF or ASP or whatever..!!

Comment: @BenRobinson The real topic is a bit more complex. Perhaps I want to set neither "value" nor "old".

Comment: @koalabruder Perhaps you better add more detail to the question, currently I understand it to be "when the value of my property doesn't change, why is the view is not updated with the new value", which does not make much sense.

Comment: If I modify the setter

Comment: Imagine you have a ComboBox without any ViewModel behind. If you select something in the ComboBox you'll see the selected value on your screen. So the view is updated if I have a setter behind it or not. So how can I reset the view to the old value?

Comment: For what it's worth, I would say that _in general_ a property setter should not be modifying the value set. Unfortunately, WPF is so reliant on properties that maybe this is unavoidable in this case. But normally, such properties are semantically confusing and should be implemented as plain methods instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the `ComboBox` read back the current value after setting the new value, you need to add a "no op" `Converter` to your `Binding` that effectively does nothing.  It's a useful little trick, as a binding will not normally check to see whether the source value actually applied matches the new value provided by the binding.  Adding a converter forces it to check.

```
public sealed class NoOpConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly NoOpConverter Instance = new NoOpConverter();

    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, 
                                 Mode=TwoWay,
                                 Converter={x:Static NoOpConverter.Instance}}"
          ... />
```

Comment: I like this answer, but from the peanut gallery, would like clarification: you're saying that the binding assumes that the property getter will always return exactly what was passed to the setter, and so is specifically _ignoring_ the `PropertyChanged` event that the setter is raising?

Comment: It ignores `PropertyChanged` events for the source property if they occur *while it is updating the source value* because it *expects* the event to be raised while setting the value (it's changing the value, after all).  But yes, the behavior is naive in that it assumes you're not going to substitute a new value for the one the binding provides.  In WPF 4.5, I believe they changed the behavior such that it always reads back after updating the source value, but for compatibility's sake, you should use this workaround anyway.