# How do I cast a dependency property in {x:bind}?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt204783) for `{X:bind}` mentions that casting in a property path is possible (the mention `{x:Bind obj.(TextBox.Text)}`) as example. I can't see how this should work in the following simple example. I tried various combinations of the type name in parens, but no success.

A common use case would be a two-way binding for a combobox, here I would cast the `SelectedValue` property from the generic object type to a more specifc type.

Example xaml page *MainPage.xaml*:

```
<Page
    x:Class="XBindTest4.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XBindTest4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind SampleList, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  SelectedValue="{x:Bind SampleData, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

Code behind *MainPage.xaml.cs*:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace XBindTest4 {

    public class SampleClass {
    }

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {

        public ObservableCollection<SampleClass> SampleList = new ObservableCollection<SampleClass>(new[] {
            new SampleClass(),
            new SampleClass()
            });

        public SampleClass SampleData { get; set; }

        public MainPage() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand, you can avaoid casting if you use the `NoOpConverter`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634526/my-c-sharp-combobox-does-not-call-the-getter-after-selecting-an-item-why/26635596#26635596). But thats not nice.

Comment: ... and I never found a structured _syntax reference_ for `{x:Bind}` property path expressions on the msdn site.

Comment: `MyProperty` is already of type `object`. It doesn't get any more general than that. The syntax you are referring to is useful to _reinterpret_ a property value by downcasting it to a needed specific type, and even then only for the purpose of referring to a property in that more-specific type. You're not doing anything like that here. Please provide a code example in which what you want to happen, does not. Explain precisely in what way it does not do what you want.

Comment: I think the problem is the two way binding: if someone changes `MyProperty`, the change cannot be assigned to the binding target, because a value of type `object` can not assigned to a more specific property.

Comment: The real world example is a selector, like a `Combobox`, the `SelectedValue` property has the type `object`, whereas in a view model the edited property has a concrete type.

Comment: I updated the example show the same effect on a combobox.

Comment: First of all, your code example _still_ does not include anything that uses the syntax that you claim to be asking about. Until you fix that, there is no way the code example can be relevant or useful. Then... _"a value of type `object` can not assigned to a more specific property"_ -- not correct. The binding system does not care about the statically declared types; as long as the runtime types match, it's fine.

Comment: Furthermore: _"`SelectedValue` property has the type `object`"_ -- this is not even an example of what you incorrectly claim would be a problem, as `SelectedValue` is the _target_ of the binding, and can always be assigned any value.

Comment: Fact is: I get a compile-time error when I try to compile the example. It says: `Invalid binding path: Sample Data: type XBindTest4.SampleClass" can not be bound to System.object without a converter.`. And I didn't use the syntax because if I try `SampleData.(local:SampleClass)` I get an error about an invalid attached property. In the linked msdn page, the code example for an attached property `{x:Bind Button22.(Grid.Row)}` looks almost like the example for the cast `{x:Bind groups3[0].(data:SampleDataGroup.Title)}`. I suspect with this syntax it is not possible to bind without a converter.

Comment: Okay...I think I understand what you are trying to do now. The syntax you actually _asked_ about is a big red herring; it has nothing to do with changing source or target property types, but rather just reinterpreting objects within the path to access their properties. Because `{x:Bind}` is a strong-typing feature, yes...you will need a converter to bind mis-matched types. It should work one-way (I think), but two-way requires matching the type in both directions, hence the converter. Note that you can still use `{Binding}`, which fully supports your scenario, at a slight cost of efficiency.

Comment: I am loathe to offer an actual answer, because I'm not actually set up to code/debug Windows 10/UWP programs. Hopefully, based on my comment above, you can choose an approach that fits your needs best (i.e. `{x:Bind}` with a converter, or `{Binding}` without one). If you get it to work to your satisfaction, I recommend you post the working code as an answer (explaining it, of course) and accept the answer to make it clear the question has been addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible with the existing syntax possiblities. That's bad because it adds unnecessary and repeating code to the binding expression: to use `{x:Bind}` in such a scenario, a converter has to be specified, even if it does nothing.

```
...
SelectedValue="{x:Bind SampleData, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NoOpConverter}}
...
```

If a converter is used, the apropriate cast is inserted into the generated file *MainPage.g.cs*:

```
this.dataRoot.SampleData = (global::XBindTest4.SampleClass)this.LookupConverter("NoOpConverter").ConvertBack((this.obj2).SelectedValue, typeof(global::XBindTest4.SampleClass), null, null);
```

Additional sources:

*NoOpConverter.cs*:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace XBindTest4 {

    public class NoOpConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
            => value;

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
            => value;

    }
}
```

Register the converter in *App.xaml*:

```
<Application
    x:Class="XBindTest4.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XBindTest4"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:NoOpConverter x:Key="NoOpConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

*MainPage.xaml.cs*:

```
<Page
    x:Class="XBindTest4.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XBindTest4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind SampleList, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  SelectedValue="{x:Bind SampleData, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NoOpConverter}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```